# unify the internal format of the cards in Vue.js with Element UI

Tags: html, vue.js, element-ui

I want to somehow unify the internal format of the cards. But this does not happen because of the different lengths of the books' names. Also, the submission button is not in a fixed position relative to the size of each card. what should I do?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbsEn.jpg)

```
<el-row :gutter="20 ">
   <el-col :span="4 " v-for="o in recommended " :key="o.isbn " :offset="0 ">
      <el-card :body-style="{ padding: '0px' } " style="margin-top:15px;height:368px;overflow:auto">
         <el-image style="width: 100%;height:240px; " :src="o.img_l " fit="cover "></el-image>
         <h4 style="padding:0 10px;margin:0 ">{{o.book_title}}</h4>
         <el-rate v-model="o.score " style="padding:10px 10px;text-align: center;" :allow-half="true"></el-rate>
         <el-button type="danger " @click="liked_btn(o) " style="min-width:128px;padding:10px 10px;text-align: center;margin-left:35px;justify-content: flex-end;">
            Submit feedback
         </el-button>
      </el-card>
   </el-col>
</el-row>
```

Comment: You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property on book name and then on hover.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Aysan I am glad that it works.